Trying to build my docker image, error class file has wrong version 65.0, should be 62.0
I'm struggling to upload my Docker image for the first time, I have been checking videos, other post about this issue here but nothing did work, I have java 21.0.3 installed and running as cmd displays.
I had established variables in my system:
W11 System variables
I run javac -source 21 -target 21 Main.java
SDK in IntelliJ is set as 21.0.3, checked modules, .idea/misc.xml, compiler... all seems to be JDK21
My project isn't using Maven or Gradle, it's a simple 3 class Java proyect.
My dockerfile:
FROM openjdk

COPY . /app/

WORKDIR /app

RUN javac Main.java

CMD ["java", "main"]

Running docker build -t todolist:1.0 .
Error:
Terminal
Have you faced something similar and am I missing something?
To build my docker image but im facing a version error

You didn't provide any details of how are you building your docker image, or where the problem actually is happening. [edit] your question and add a  [mre].

Don't use images to convey config/code/errors.  Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

From the image: /bin/sh -c javac Main.java Note that javac is an executable. Are you sure that you need the /bin/sh -c ?
